# Esperar datos de localstorage para cargar componente angular

Tags: array, angular

Tengo que verificar 2 arrays en el localstorage y si no están o están vacíos necesito hacer una consulta a una api y esperar la respuesta antes de cargar un componente.
La api siempre retorna un array de mas de 100 elemento que se usan para hacer cálculos en otra parte de la aplicación, por lo que necesito que si o si se espere a que el localstorage tenga la data para seguir.

Intente con un resolver pero no se me ocurre como hacer para esperar a que el localstorage si o si tenga data.

**ACTUALIZO**

Este es el codigo para obtener los datos de la api. Yo necesito que esta función, que esta en un servicio, responda solamente cuando el localstorage tenga datos. Puede ser con o sin actualizar nuevos datos.

Actualmente esto se ejecutar en un resolver, pero podría ejecutarlo en un guard que protege las rutas, lo que necesito si o si es que el componente no se cargue hasta que el localstorage tenga los datos disponibles

```
setCotizaciones(){
  let last_update = localStorage.getItem('last_update')!;
  let ls_cotizaciones_d = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cotizaciones_d')!) || [];
  
  const fechaInicio = (ls_cotizaciones_d.length > 0) ? ls_cotizaciones_d.at(0).fecha : '2022-11-01';
  
  const fec = undefined;
  const fechaActual = moment(fec).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

  const actualizar_cot_d = !last_update || (
                              last_update && last_update != fechaActual && (
                                (moment(fechaActual).weekday() != 5 && moment(fechaActual).weekday() != 6) || 
                                ( ls_cotizaciones_d.length > 0 &&
                                  (moment(fechaActual).weekday() == 5 && moment(ls_cotizaciones_d.at(0).fecha).diff(moment(fec),'days') < -1 ) || 
                                  (moment(fechaActual).weekday() == 6 && moment(ls_cotizaciones_d.at(0).fecha).diff(moment(fec),'days') < -2 ) 
                                )
                              )
                            )                            

  localStorage.setItem('last_update',fechaActual)
  
  if(actualizar_cot_d){
    const fechaActualRequest = moment(fec).add(1,'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    const cotizacionesRequest = this.cotizaciones_request(`${this.url_cotizaciones_d}/${fechaInicio}/${fechaActualRequest}`);

    cotizacionesRequest.subscribe((resp: any[]) => {
      const cotizaciones_d: Cotizacion[] = [];

      for (const cot of resp) {
        let fechaCot = cot[0].split('/');
        if (fechaCot.length > 1) {
          let cotizacion = {
            fecha: `${fechaCot[2]}-${fechaCot[1]}-${fechaCot[0]}`,
            valor: parseFloat(cot[2].replace(',', '.'))
          };

          const old_cot: any = cotizaciones_d.find((c: Cotizacion) => c.fecha == cotizacion.fecha);
          if (old_cot) {
            cotizacion = old_cot;
            old_cot.valor = cotizacion.valor;
          } else {
            cotizaciones_d.push(cotizacion);
          }

        }
      }

      localStorage.setItem('cotizaciones_d', JSON.stringify(cotizaciones_d.concat(ls_cotizaciones_d)));
    })
  } 
}
```

Comment: Agrega el código para que te podamos ayudar, por otro lado checa el ciclo de vida de Angular, es probable que eso te pueda ayudar.

Comment: A ver si asi esta bien editado y se entiende mejor lo que busco. Gracias

Comment: Lo que pusiste funciona, o sea, te regresa los datos que necesitas?

Comment: Si funciona, el problema es que le toma algo de tiempo completarlo y necesito convertirlo en una promesa o alguna otra forma que solo continue la ejecucion cuando el localstorage tiene esos datos. Como esta ahora, la primera vez sigue la ejecucion y da error cuando se intenta usar ese array

Comment: Suena mas a algo que debe estar en un guard para que espere a que se haga el request al api

Comment: El tema es que no siempre tiene que hacer la request a la api. Porque si los datos estan en el localstorage actualizados (se actualizan una vez al dia) no tiene que hacer ninguna request. De todos modos, puedo ver de llevarlo todo al backend, pero como podria hacer en un guard (que ya tengo para validar usuario) para que espere la respuesta de esta ruta del backend?

Comment: Al pensar en algo como lo que dices se me ocurre otra cosa, no sería más factible verificar en el componente si existen datos en el localstorage? Además dices que tienes todo esto dentro de un servicio y luego parece que dentro de ese servicio estas usando otro servicio para hacer requests.

Comment: Luego si no me equivoco y analizando más el código, tienes un O(n) aunque sea un numero de elementos constante (100) con ese `for` y luego usas dentro `find` en cada iteración, lo cual por si solo es otro O(n), lo cual daría O(n^2), si buscas una gráfica del tiempo de ejecución vas a ver porque se tarda tanto y lo que pasará si cada vez tienes más elementos.

Comment: Para esto podrías usar operadores de RxJS, como `form`, `filter`, `first`, `form` convierte todo a un Observable, `filter` pues filtra los datos pero lo importante acá es que hace algo así como 'bajo demanda' y de forma perezosa, mientras que `first` te da el primer elemento que emite un Observable, en este caso sería el primer elemento que cumple con la condición establecida.